# Tensorflow does not see gpu on pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm

Specifications:
System: Ubuntu 18.0.4
Tensorflow:1.9.0,
cudnn=7.2.1

Interpreter project: anaconda environment.

When I run the script on terminal with the same anaconda env, it works fine. Using pycharm, it does not work!! What is the issue ?

Comment: Which do you use  to install tensorflow, `pip install tensorflow` or `pip install tensorflow-gpu`?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter** and set the same python environment used by Anaconda.

Comment: Sure, I do it as I said in my question! I use the same environment as the one use on the terminal

Comment: You probably have multiple versions of Pythons, check with `which python` also define "does not work" , error? warning ? simply doesnt run?stack trace